# Populating a cursor with a rowtype variable

Tags: oracle

No amount of googling seems to find the answer to this one...

I'm trying to modify Oracle sproc that that currently pulling values out of some tables and moving them to other tables.

It has a ROWTYPE variable that is defined like this:

```
myRow my_tbl%ROWTYPE;
```

Right now, the sproc does some logic that populates the rowtype variable and then uses it to populate a table:

```
INSERT INTO MY_TBL
(   col1,
    col2,
    col3,
    -snip-
) 
VALUES (
    myRow.aValue,
    myRow.aValue2,
    myRow.aValu3,
    -snip-
)
```

Instead of populating a table, I want to use the ROWTYPE to populate a cursor that is returned to a Web app. However, I can't find a way to do this ROWTYPE -> REF CURSOR conversion. Is this possible? If not, is there a way to manually populate a cursor with data drawn  from various tables and using some complex logic? I'm using Oracle 10g.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tricky part about this is that you are using a REF CURSOR, which is intended for a set of rows to return data for just a single row.  I imagine you are just doing this because your web app understands ref cursors and how to get them from Oracle, but not object types.  I am also guessing that for some reason you can't just write a single select statment to retrieve and manipulate the data as needed (this is the easiest way, so with more info we can possibly help you out to achieve it).

There are a few ways I can think of to do this, none of them very pretty, so hopefully someone else will chime in with a better idea.

1) Create the cursor by selecting your calculated variables from dual

```
DECLARE
    refcur SYS_REFCURSOR;
    myRow TBL%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
    myRow.aValue := 1;
    myRow.aValue2 := 3;
    myRow.aValue3 := 5;    
    OPEN refcur
    FOR
        select
            myRow.aValue,
            myRow.aValue2,
            myRow.aValue3
        from
            dual;
    CLOSE refcur;
END;
```

2) Create a pipelined function that returns a table of your rowtype, and create your cursor from a select from that function.

Comment: Yes ... we just have cursors to work with. Theoretically, I could just use one monster query to do this, but it would be ugly! I hoping to be able to break it up a bit. What would the "select from dual" syntax look like in this case?

Comment: I have added an example of what the select from dual syntax would look like.

Comment: In real life we wouldn't close the cursor, we would pass it or return it to a consumer.

Comment: @APC - Yes, that is correct.. Thanks for adding that clarification.

Comment: Though, it's out of question,as it came to close for what I'm searching, could some one tell me what will be index of the ref_cursor if I'm trying to call from java using callableStatement.registerOutParameter() method?

Answer (score 0):

The select from dual would be something like

```
select  myRow.aValue,
        myRow.aValue2,
        myRow.aValu3
from dual;
```

You should be able to declare a cursor for that.

There is a good writeup of REF CURSOR at http://psoug.org/reference/ref_cursors.html

Comment: Could you post some code on how the cursor declaration should look like? What type should it be? How do you get the values into the cursor?